# Issue with React form validation keeping form state in Application state

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I have recatpcha in my signup form. The component has states as:

```
firstname: null,
lastname: null,
email: null,
password: null,
recaptcha: false
```

and before submitting the form, I validate all of the details and check if `recaptcha` have been submitted using `if(recaptcha)`.
But any technical person could go to the React dev tools and mark `recaptcha` as true and then submits the form. they just by passed the recaptcha validation. Also, with other states as well(e.g `isAuthenticated`), they can change State from dev tools.

How this need to be taken care of?

Comment: In general, the backend should be the source of truth for authenticated data.

Comment: Why don't we see the `State` of other react application like Instagram? Because they are Server-side-rendered?